# Erro server 500 reverse openshif com django

Tags: python, django, deploy, openshift

Fiz o deploy de uma aplicação no openshift e basicamente a mesma se trata de um crud, oque acontece, sempre que tento cadastrar um novo cliente o servidor me retorna "server erro 500", alguém sabe me dizer o porque deste erro?, estou achando que o problema pode ser por conta do meu get_absolute_url no meu models, o problema e que localmente a aplicação roda tranquilo, porém no no ar ela me retorna este erro.

detalhe estou usando generic views:

```
#views.py
class ListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ClientMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'core/client_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'clients'
    paginate_by = 10

#models.py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy("profile_view")
```

Comment: Você possui `DEBUG = False`, certo? Isso torna difícil saber qual é o erro, pois existem muitas possibilidades... Tem como colocá-lo `True` só pra testar? Caso contrário, será necessário olhar os logs de erro para saber com certeza. Algumas possibilidades: 1) o token contra CSRF está faltando (comum, se o problema for só no POST e não no GET); 2) O setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS` está faltando. Se o problema for **só** nessa view específica, e não nas outras, desconsidere esse comentário.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eis meu problema com o DEBUG ativado: table core_client has no column named address, após acessar o servidor via ssh sabe me dizer como deletar meu bando de dados (mysql) para corrigir o erro?, não encontrei meu banco em local algum aqui, e o estranho e que quando crio um superuser via command line o mesmo aparece no banco mas quando tento acessa o /admin/ ele acusa que não existe o usuário cadastrado.

Comment: Será que a versão web do seu sistema está usando o banco de dados certo? Verifique seu settings. Infelizmente não sei nada de openshift, então não tem como eu ajudá-lo nisso... Mas pelo menos identificamos mais ou menos onde está o problema (no banco, e não no seu código). P.S. Você está usando migrações? (*migrations*) Mexeu no banco desde o último deploy? (se esse não for seu primeiro deploy, é claro)

Comment: Estou usando Django 1.6, realmente esta estranho esse caso do meu banco de dados, porque via ssh não encontro o mesmo em lugar algum, vou fazer algumas alterações aqui para ver se consigo fixar o erro, desde já agradeço o teu apoio.

Comment: não encontrava o banco de dados porque o DATABASES do myqsl estava localizado no settings errado.

resolvi meu problema do "has no column named" deletando o banco de dado usando ...
1: $ rhc cartridge remove mysql-5.5 --app myphpapp1
2: $ rhc cartridge add mysql-5.5 --app myphpapp1
3: $ rhc app-stop myphpapp1
4: $ rhc app-start myphpapp1

Comment: todos os seus problemas resolvidos então dhelbegor?

Comment: @Rubico, Desculpe a demora no retorno, foram sim, obrigado a atenção de todos.